# PFLoadingView in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In the PFQueryTableView, there is a view called PFLoadingView and I am trying to amend this view :

Here is my code in swift :

```
func PFLoadingStyle()
{
        for view: UIView in self.view.subviews as [UIView]
        {
            if NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "PFLoadingView"
            {
                for loadingView : UIView in view.subviews as [UIView]
                {
                    if loadingView .isKindOfClass(UILabel)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets to the UILabel where it usually says "Loading...", I have called this function from ViewDidLayoutSubviews (which i think is correct). I cannot seem to find the Views information to what I should be amending. If I run this now the Loaing UILabel is at the top right of my screen. Where is the class information in Parse so I find out what to change ?

I also what to change the Activity Monitor to something more custom.

Hope you understand my question - i need to find what UILabels etc, to change to make it back the middle again and to change the font. i.e. need to find out how to customise the PFLoadingView.

EDIT ::

i have added :

```
func PFLoadingStyle()
{
    var Textcolour = UIColor.blueColor()
        for view: UIView in self.view.subviews as [UIView]
        {
            if NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "PFLoadingView"
            {
                for loadingView : UIView in view.subviews as [UIView]
                {
                    if loadingView .isKindOfClass(UILabel)
                    {
                        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
                        label.textColor = Textcolour
                        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                        label.text = "I'am a test label"
                        loadingView.addSubview(label)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This adds a new label when the PFTableView is loading, but the original one is still there too. If I can remove the original then it will work fine. Then I can add a CGRect to the label and everything will be ok.

Comment: You could achieve this by using UIAppearance, `[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:@[NSStringFromClass(@"PFLoadingView")]]`

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question by this code :

```
func PFLoadingStyle()
{
    var Textcolour = UIColor.blueColor()
        for view: UIView in self.view.subviews as [UIView]
        {
            if NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "PFLoadingView"
            {
                for loadingView : UIView in view.subviews as [UIView]
                {
                    if loadingView .isKindOfClass(UILabel)
                    {
                        var label = loadingView as UILabel
                        label.font = UIFont(name: "Cantarell", size: 14)
                        label.text="Loading Events"


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```